# limitar quantidade de caracteres por linha em uma textbox do tipo multiline

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net, textarea

Gostaria que no meu campo permitisse até 47 caracteres em cada linha, porém estou com um problema quando o usuário deixa uma linha e continue digitado. Porque ele quebra a linha antes dele completar os 47 caracteres. segue abaixo o código:

```
 function mascaraCAMPO(campo, e) {         
        var texto = campo.value;         
            if ((texto.length % 47 == 0) && (texto.length != 0)) 
            {               
                campo.value = campo.value + "\n";                    
            }                
        }
 <asp:Textbox ID="txtValue" runat="server" onkeypress="mascaraCAMPO(this,event)" onpaste="return false" ondrop="return false" TextMode="MultiLine" maxlength="4653"    style="resize: none;width:400px" Rows="20" Columns="47"  ></asp:Textbox>
```

Comment: exatamente, quando o usuário aperta enter.

Comment: Mas ele tem o limite de 47 cars. por linha, deixar a linha em branco não viola o limite.

Comment: linha em branco eu desconsidero no codebehind, o problema é na contagem. do length que só está contando os caracteres digitados . Por exemplo, se eu completo os 47 caracteres, e digito algo de 1 caractere na linha de baixo e quebro a linha e digito outra coisa ele continua contando e quebra a linha como se fosse da mesma linha.

Comment: simplesmente não deixar digitar mais que 47 caracteres por linha se passar disso ele joga para a linha de baixo.

Comment: Se você montar um array com as linhas do campo e verificar em cada posição do array, não daria certo?